# Webdriver - Not able to click the input type =submit login

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am building cucumber/webdriver script in java.

The login page takes email and password to sign in...

The script fills the emailid and password

But the click on SignIn button doesnt work..

Below is the link
http://accountsdemo.herokuapp.com/users/sign_in

Have tried
By signInLocator=By.name("commit");
and also 
By signInLocator=By.xpath("//input[@type='submit']");

Below is the Java code for the same

```
public void the_user_click_sign_in() throws Throwable{
    driver.findElement(signInLocator).click();
}
```

Not sure if i am doing anything wrong here

Comment: What error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an account for this site so I can't test the login but I can verify that I am clicking the right button.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://accountsdemo.herokuapp.com/users/sign_in");
WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='commit']"));
System.out.println(button.getAttribute("outerHTML"));
```

This will print

```
<input name="commit" value="Sign in" type="submit">
```

which is the HTML for the Sign in button so the code below should work.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='commit']")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

From selenium IDE you can easily get the location of the element using different locator values.
you need to select "Select" option in IDE, then using mouse click on specified element. Then you will get different locator values like css value, xpath value,etc.. from them you can choose any one according to your choice. 
For you query i tried the same what i said. the result is listed below
name=commit
`css=input[name="commit"]
//input[@name='commit']
//form[@id='new_user']/input[3]
//input[3]`

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting `noSuchElementException` then try adding wait in your script before submit button :-

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 0):

Still no success.. I am sure that am missing something and its related to wait/noelement exception..

Below is the complete code

userid:abhi@gmail.com password:password

```
public class SignInPage {

By userEmailByTextLocator = By.id("user_email");
By userPasswordTextLocator = By.id("user_password");
By signInLocator=By.cssSelector("input[name='commit']");

WebDriver driver;

public SignInPage(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
}
public void the_user_enters_email_id_to_sign_in(String email) {
driver.findElement(userEmailByTextLocator).sendKeys(email);
}

public void the_user_enters_password_to_sign_in(String password) {
driver.findElement(userPasswordTextLocator).sendKeys(password);

}
public void the_user_click_sign_in() throws Throwable{
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(signInLocator).click();
}
public boolean the_user_is_on_signed_in_page() throws Throwable
{ return        
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href='/users/sign_out']")).
  isDisplayed(); 
}

}
```

`